# How to read path from relative path via the library used in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am trying to use `anyNpmPackage` in meteor project on test.

I have done `meteor npm install anyNpmPackage`

In my package.js i have

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
    api.use([
      'anyNpmPackage'
    ]);
    api.addFiles('tests/server/methods.js', 'server');
});
```

Now `anyNpmPackage` uses `anyOtherNpmPackage` internally

On of the line of `anyOtherNpmPackage` is

`myModule = fs.readFileSync(require.resolve("../include/module.js"));`

And when i do the meteor test

I get error `Error: Cannot find module '../include/module.js'`

And when i debugged just above that line

`console.log(fs.readdirSync('../../'))` the result was `[ 'server', 'web.browser' ]` and `console.log(__dirname)` was resulting to `/node_modules/jsonpath/lib`

where `jsonpath` is `anyOtherNpmPackage`

Any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Npm.depends](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#npm-dependencies) when your Meteor package depends on a **npm** package.

**EDIT:**
I created the following package inside a Meteor app and it works:

package.js

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'npmtest',
  version: '0.0.1',
  // Brief, one-line summary of the package.
  summary: '',
  // URL to the Git repository containing the source code for this package.
  git: '',
  // By default, Meteor will default to using README.md for documentation.
  // To avoid submitting documentation, set this field to null.
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.5.1');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.mainModule('npmtest.js');

});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('npmtest');
  api.mainModule('npmtest-tests.js');
});

Npm.depends({
    'jsonpath':'1.0.0'
})
```

npmtest-tests.js

```
// Import Tinytest from the tinytest Meteor package.
import { Tinytest } from "meteor/tinytest";

// Import and rename a variable exported by npmtest.js.
import { name as packageName } from "meteor/npmtest";
const jp = Npm.require("jsonpath");
// Write your tests here!
// Here is an example.
Tinytest.add('npmtest - example', function (test) {
  console.log("here")
  const cities = [
    { name: "London", "population": 8615246 },
    { name: "Berlin", "population": 3517424 },
    { name: "Madrid", "population": 3165235 },
    { name: "Rome",   "population": 2870528 }
  ];
  const names = jp.query(cities, '$..name');

  test.equal(names[0], "London");
});
```

**EDIT2:**
Note : I never used `npm install`

Comment: Yes even after putting that into Npm.depends, the result is same. FYI, the `anyOtherNpmPackage` is accessible, only thing is its relative path is messed up. So `fs` APIs are srewed up.

Comment: It should not be the same. Atmosphere doesn't know anything about npm packages.
I tested a meteor package with <code>jsonpath</code> as 1 lvl npm package dependency and it worked. So we need more infos about your "anyNpmPackage"

Comment: thanks but that does not helps me.. anyNpmPackage is `allrounder` that i can relate that with tinytest. In your example, the tinytest should have been just another normal npm package, nothing to relate with Atmosphere. And that tinytest should be using jsonpath internally.

Comment: i would be really greatfull if you can help me., i am really stuck with meteor custom env directory. Can we have a chat sometime plz